# C# - Troubles with IEnumerable.Where

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I'm currently working on a little program, which should get the information scanned by a barcode scanner (a so-called "HID") via the Raw-Input API.

I've read many tutorials about that and i think I'm understanding how it works. I'm using an IEnumerable to enumerate the input-devices. But now the compiler screams that the `Where`-Method is not known for an IEnumerable.

I've going through the MSDN-Articles regarding the IEnumerable and if I have understand the articles right, the `Where`-Method should be part of it.

Below a little snippet with the place i want to use the Where:

```
var rawInputDevice in rawDeviceEnumerator.Devices
    .Where(d => d.DeviceType == Win32.RawInputDeviceType.Keyboard)
```

Can someone please give me an approach?
I think its just a little thing I'm overseeing.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Do you have a `using` directive for the `System.Linq` namespace? Is your input source actually an `IEnumerable` or an `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`? (Most LINQ operators only work with `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: Also are you referring to `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @itreniets : What is the 'Devices' object? Is it a collection implementing IEnumerable ?

Comment: Did you mean `foreach (var rawInputDevice in ...)`? Again, please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, *not* a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are noting typically comes from older Collection types before .net 3.0, which introduced generic types.

The method you want to use is `Enumerable.Where(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T,bool> predicate)`. However `rawDeviceEnumerator.Devices` seems to be an `IEnumerable` and NOT `IEnumerable<T>`. Assuming you are using the `RawInputDeviceEnumerator` from http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=571&ver=vcs&PHPSESSID=5f4393ed0b6c7c205851a834e657e8be, then you have several options.

First. Change the code from

```
    public IEnumerable Devices
    {
        get
        {
            return this._devices;
        }
    }
```

To

```
    public IEnumerable<RawInputDevice> Devices
    {
        get
        {
            return this._devices;
        }
    }
```

Or you can use

```
var rawInputDevice in rawDeviceEnumerator.Devices
                  .Cast<RawInputDevice>()
                  .Where(d => d.DeviceType == Win32.RawInputDeviceType.Keyboard)
```

Comment: Dear Aron, thanks for your answer. That was the Key! 
But what i not really understand is, why i have to cast the Devices to RawInputDevice? Shouldn't be the rawDeviceEnumerator.Devices a list of items from type RawInputDevice?

Comment: @itreniets It SHOULD be (specifically it should have been of type `IEnumerable<RawInputDevice>`). However it is likely the code was written before `IEnumerable<T>` was part of .net and WAY WAY WAY before Linq.

Comment: Dear Aron, thanks for the information. Now it's much clearlier for me. :-)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [`Enumeration.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). It appears to 'add' methods to existing classes bases on the type of the class and it's base classes or interfaces.

If you include `System.Linq` as namespace in your code files, you will see this extension method will appear on every object that implements `IEnumerable<TSource>`, for example `List<T>` or `int[]`.